# Entity Framework Core 3.1 and Oracle 12c - Encoding Issue with modelBuilder.Entity<>.HasData

Tags: .net-core, entity-framework-core, oracle12c, ef-core-3.1

It seems like I´ve an issue with encoding using EF Core 3.1 and Oracle 12 when using migrations to populate data.

I try to populate my DB with some values and I´d like to do that during migration.

The entity class looks like this:

```
    public class AlertTemplate
    {
        public int AlertTemplateId { get; set; }
        public short AlertTemplateVersion { get; set; }
        public short NumberOfValues { get; set; }

        [Column(TypeName = "nvarchar2(50)")]
        public string Name { get; set; }
        [Column(TypeName = "nvarchar2(200)")]
        public string ShortDescription { get; set; }
        public string Description { get; set; }
        public int StartingAlertLevel { get; set; }
    }
```

So I´ve added this to my DBContexts OnModelCreating:

```
           modelBuilder.Entity<AlertTemplate>().HasData(
                new AlertTemplate { AlertTemplateId = 0, AlertTemplateVersion = 1, Name = "Unspecified Alert Alert", StartingAlertLevel = 20, ShortDescription = "An alert was raised but there was a misconfiguration. So instead this generic alert was raised.", Description = "This generic alert was raised because something wen´t wrong while raising a specific alert. Most probably some kind of misconfiguration.\nThe following additional Information is available for the alert that should have been raised:\n\nAlertId:{0} in Version:{1}\nServer:{2}\nError/Exception:{3}", NumberOfValues = 4 },
```

I do not set any encoding or collation intentionally anywhere - yet. Up to now I was relying on EF magic (aka defaults)...

After executing the migration to my database I see this in the description column:

```
This generic alert was raised because something wen¿t wrong while raising a specific alert. Most probably some kind of misconfiguration.
The following additional Information is available for the alert that should have been raised:

AlertId:{0} in Version:{1}
Server:{2}
Error/Exception:{3}
```

It´s probably not obvious at a first glance so: The problem is the wen**¿**t . That and the fact that I misspelled it but let's focus on the **¿** that shouldn´t be there instead of the "´".

I checked the encoding of the .cs-File the migration generates. It is encoded in UTF8 (with BOM).
In that file the "´" still is a "´":

```
            migrationBuilder.InsertData(
                table: "AlertTemplates",
                columns: new[] { "AlertTemplateId", "AlertTemplateVersion", "Description", "Name", "NumberOfValues", "ShortDescription", "StartingAlertLevel" },
                values: new object[] { 0, (short)1, @"This generic alert was raised because something wen´t wrong while raising a specific alert. Most probably some kind of misconfiguration.
The following additional Information is available for the alert that should have been raised:

AlertId:{0} in Version:{1}
Server:{2}
Error/Exception:{3}", "Unspecified Alert Alert", (short)4, "An alert was raised but there was a misconfiguration. So instead this generic alert was raised.", 20 });
```

When I fetch that entry from DB I also get the ¿.
So something seems to happen when inserting with migrationBuilder.

I also checked the script that is generated:
using the package manager console: script-migration
Again... Everything seems fine there...

```
BEGIN
INSERT INTO "AlertTemplates" ("AlertTemplateId", "AlertTemplateVersion", "Description", "Name", "NumberOfValues", "ShortDescription", "StartingAlertLevel")
VALUES (0, 1, N'This generic alert was raised because something wen´t wrong while raising a specific alert. Most probably some kind of misconfiguration.
The following additional Information is available for the alert that should have been raised:

AlertId:{0} in Version:{1}
Server:{2}
Error/Exception:{3}', N'Unspecified Alert Alert', 4, N'An alert was raised but there was a misconfiguration. So instead this generic alert was raised.', 20);
END;
```

I also looked at the script to check if any collation or encoding is set and there is nothing like that. I also checked the value types: all strings seem to be translated to nvarchar2 either with maxlen or the length I provide in the attribute.

I updated the Entry directly in the DB using SQL Developer and changed the "¿" to "´". After that when reading into a string I actually get "´" so this issue seems to be linked to what migration does.

I also tried inserting the entry using my entity class

```
dbcontext.AlertTemplates.Add(new AlertTemplate [...]
dbcontext.SaveChanges()
```

That does work and the "´" is not replaced with "¿". However I would like to use migrations to update the database and my template table.

I was looking for a way to set encoding and or collation but I only found examples for MySQL when actually including oracle in my searches.

Besides the fact that I misspelled "went" - what else could be done about that ?

Comment: It might help to show the mysql examples

Comment: EF doesn't do any magic. There shouldn't be any encodings involved - .NET strings are Unicode, Windows strings are Unicode and the database uses Unicode fields (`nvarchar`). What's strange is the *text* - `wen´t `. Is your *source file* stored as UTF8? Or is it stored in your local codepage? `¿` has no special meaning, which suggests your source was stored using one codepage and compiled using a different one

Comment: @mcalex it won't - MySQL has no explicit Unicode type, while Oracle (and the other major commercial databases) do. Oracle doesn't need a specific encoding to store Unicode data. The problem was caused before the text even reached the database

Comment: I just checked with notepad++ the migration file is stored in UTF-8 (with BOM). I will update the question...

Comment: I also tried to add those entries outside of the migration using my entity class... That does work fine... So it seems like it is limited to the migration that ef core tools generate / migrationBuilder.InsertData somehow

Comment: You can check what insert query is generated using `dotnet ef migrations script` and check what is entity framework trying to insert.

Comment: Thank you. I checked using "scrip-migration". Unfortunately the output seems ok. I updated the question.

Comment: Looks like you have copied the text from somewhere and pasted into the code. Could you remove the apostrophe and try to put it again?

Comment: No copy paste involved. While "wen´t" by itself was a typo - I exactly typed it like that in the OnModelCreating / HasData Statement. And it should not be translated to ¿ somewhere between my code and the database. To me this indicates an issue with encoding and that´s why I´m interested in solving that issue more than in correcting the typo at this point :-)